# Change Modifier Key While Application is frontmost

Tags: mac, keyboard, script, keybindings

What I'm trying to accomplish is to intercept or change Command and replace it with Control for use while another application is running and frontmost.

Is there a way to temporarily change modifier keys on the Mac using a script?

For example, an applescript could be saved as Stay Open and would intercept a keystroke and change the keystroke to another keystroke.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>EMACS</appname>
    <equal>org.gnu.Emacs</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <only>EMACS</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::CONTROL_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::CONTROL_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```